# Was bedeutet orwellhaft?

Tags: meaning, etymology

[In diesem Artikel](https://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/soziales/amazonas-irland-droht-brasilien-mit-blockade-von-handelsabkommen-a-1283308.html) wird in letztem Satz von *orwellhaft* gesprochen. Was bedeutet das, bzw wie ist dieser Begriff/Vergleich entstanden: Auf welche Eigenschaft oder welches Schriftstück von welchem Orwell zielt es ab? Ich vermute es hat was mit George Orwell zu tun, aber ich bin zu unbelesen, als dass ich es wüsste.

> Der irische Premier Varadkar sagte dazu: "Präsident Bolsonaros Versuche, Umweltschutzorganisationen für die Feuer verantwortlich zu machen, ist orwellhaft."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Orwellhaft" beziehungsweise das englische "orwellian" beschreibt [laut Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Orwellian), dass etwas den totalitären Methoden ähnelt, die George Orwell in seinen Werken anprangert. Zu diesen Methoden gehört Überwachung, Zensur und Propaganda, aber auch die Umdeutung der Sprache und sogar Gehirnwäsche.

In Orwells Roman "1984" verwenden die totalitären Machthaber auch diese Instrumente. Beispielsweise ist [Newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak), in der deutschen Fassung [Neusprech](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusprech) ein Vorhaben, die Sprache der Menschen durch eine neue Sprache zu ersetzen. Denken und Sprache beeinflussen sich gegenseitig. Wenn die neue Sprache es nicht mehr zulässt, bestimmte Dinge zu formulieren, wird es auch schwieriger, diese Dinge zu denken. Oder die neue Sprache gibt Dingen eine veränderte Bedeutung, weil sie durch andere Begriffe bezeichnet werden.

Ein Beispiel aus der realen Welt: Vor einiger Zeit hat die amerikanische Regierung bestritten, dass sie Lügen verbreitet habe. Man habe nur *alternative Fakten* dargestellt. Das klingt doch gleich ganz anders ...

Ein solcher neuer Begriff in der Welt von 1984 ist [Doublethink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublethink) beziehungsweise [Doppeldenk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeldenk). Damit ist die (nach Aussage der Machthaber erstrebenswerte) Fähigkeit gemeint, widersprüchliche Aussagen gleichzeitig zu akzeptieren. Etwas ist wahr, und das Gegenteil davon ist gleichzeitig auch wahr.

Ein Slogan der regierenden Partei ist beispielsweise

> War is Peace
>
> Freedom is Slavery
>
> Ignorance is Strength

auf Deutsch

> Krieg ist Frieden
>
> Freiheit ist Sklaverei
>
> Unwissenheit ist Stärke

Etwas Ähnliches versucht, nach Meinung des irischen Premiers, der in dem Artikel zitiert wird, auch Präsident Bolsonaro. Er versucht den Menschen weiszumachen, dass die Umweltschutz­organisationen, deren Aufgabe der Schutz des Regenwalds ist, *gleichzeitig* diejenigen sind, die den Regenwald zerstören. Deshalb bezeichnet Premier Varadkar diese Taktik als "orwellhaft".

Answer (score 3):

„Orwellhaft“ wird im Zusammenhang mit Überwachung und Zensur verwendet und ist damit wohl ein Verweise auf George Orwells 1984.

> Er findet es unheimlich, „orwellhaft“, dass dieser Hubschrauber über uns kreist.
> https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/autoren/eine-begegnung-mit-robert-harris-der-spion-der-nicht-siegte-12634290.html
>
> Templin ist selbst Stasi-Spitzel gewesen, [...] eine orwellhaft anmutende Quelle zum Verständnis dessen, was man die "Identität" der DDR genannt hat, ist seit Montag im Handel
> https://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/soziales/amazonas-irland-droht-brasilien-mit-blockade-von-handelsabkommen-a-1283308.html

Cambridge Dictionary erklärt dazu:

> used to describe a political system in which the government tries to control every part of people's lives, similar to that described in the novel "Nineteen Eighty Four", by George Orwell

Der Satz im Artikel

> Präsident Bolsonaros Versuche, Umweltschutzorganisationen für die Feuer verantwortlich zu machen, ist orwellhaft.
>
> (President Bolsonaro’s efforts to blame the fires on environmental NGOs is Orwellian) https://www.thejournal.ie/varadkar-bolsonaro-fires-4778620-Aug2019/

ist auch mit dieser Definition schwierig zu deuten, denn Organisationen die Schuld an Waldbränden zuzuschieben, ist eher ein schlechtes Mittel, um das Leben der einzelnen Bürger zu kontrollieren. Varadkar zielt wohl eher darauf ab, anzudeuten, Bolsonaro versuche die öffentliche Meinung schamlos zu beeinflussen.

Comment: Bezieht sich der Eintrag im Cambridge Dictionary auf *orwellhaft* oder auf *orwellesque* oder ähnlich?

Comment: @Arsak Auf orwellian wie im Originalzitat.

Comment: Ich denke, dass sollte so auch in der Antwort stehen. Im Moment liest es sich, als hätte das Camb. Dict. einen deutschsprachigen Eintrag

Comment: Henning Kockerbeck hat es richtig erfasst. Aus dem Kontext lässt sich zwanglos folgern, dass es um das Verdrehen von Tatsachen gehen muss, nicht um Überwachung.

Comment: "Organisationen die Schuld an Waldbränden zuzuschieben, ist eher ein schlechtes Mittel, um das Leben der einzelnen Bürger zu kontrollieren" - die öffentliche Meinung zu beeinflussen ist durchaus eine Form der Kontrolle über das Leben der Bürger, und genauso wird der Begriff dort verwendet.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist die (eine) deutsche Art, einen Eigennamen in ein Adjektiv zu verwandeln. Dazu wird einfach ein *-haft* an den Eigennamen angehängt. Das funktioniert auch mit manchen Substantiven und führt zu Adjektiven wie

> schadhaft

Das Englische verwendet einen ähnlichen Mechanismus, um das Gleiche zu tun, dort entstehen dann Adjektive wie

> orwellian

mit derselben Bedeutung - es beschreibt ein politisches System wie das in Orwells Roman *1984*, in dem die Regierung danach strebt, jeden Aspekt des Lebens der Bürger zu kontrollieren (Siehe auch "[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/orwellian)"). Was genau der im verlinkten Artikel dargestellte Sachverhalt damit zu tun hat ist mir auch nicht vollkomen klar, es handelt sich aber eindeutig um ein aus dem Englischen übersetztes [Zitat](https://www.rte.ie/news/2019/0823/1070418-french-concern-about-brazil-fires/) eines irischen Politikers.

Comment: Allerdings verbinde ich 'orwellian' mit Überwachung und Propaganda, basierend auf Orwell's buch "1984". Ich verstehe nicht ganz wie das zu der Verwendung im verlinkten Artikel passen soll, wonach es orwellhaft ist, dass der brasilianische Präsident versucht Umweltorganisationen Schuld für die Brände zu geben.

Comment: @jarnbjo Was er denn gemeint haben könnte, ist mir auch nicht ganz klar. Da es aber ein Ire ist, der das gesagt hat, wird er wohl "orwellian" gesagt haben: https://www.rte.ie/news/2019/0823/1070418-french-concern-about-brazil-fires/ - Der Spiegel hat es nur wörtlich ins Deutsche übersetzt.

Comment: Und welche Bedeutung ist das nun? Die Frage wurde nicht beantwortet.

Comment: Die Bedeutung ist, dass es einen Bezug zu Orwell gibt. Das ist alles, was man sagen kann, soweit es um die deutsche Sprache geht. Im Zweifel weiß nur der Autor selbst, wie er das gemeint hat.

Comment: @infinitezero Es bezieht sich am wahrscheinlichsten auf die von Orwell entworfenen Zukunftsvisionen.

Comment: Also, "orwellian" wird in der englischen Sprache so häufig verwendet, dass es auch in mehreren Wörterbüchern aufgeführt ist und es gibt auch ein Wikipedia-Artikel dazu. Das Wort hat die Bedeutung "wie das politische System in 1984" und ist nicht nur eine schwammige, unklare Referenz zu Orwell als Person. Allerdings passt das nicht so ganz zu der Verwendung in dem verlinkten Artikel.

Comment: @jarnbjo   *Orwellhaft* in Bezug auf den derzeitigen Regierungschef Brasliens meint natürlich (da gibt es wenig Zweifel) die gruselig-diktatorische Seite dieser Regierung, die jegliche Opposition (hier: Umweltschützer) mit skrupellosen Methoden einzudämmen versucht und möglichst ganze Lügengebäude errichtet, um die Bevölkerung hinter der Regierung zu vereinen.

Comment: @jarnbjo: "Allerdings verbinde ich 'orwellian' mit (...) Propaganda"; "dass der brasilianische Präsident versucht Umweltorganisationen Schuld für die Brände zu geben." - ist Letzteres nicht eben genau ein Beispiel für die von dir selber angesprochene Propaganda?

Comment: In *1984* gibt es ein "Ministerium für Wahrheit", das beliebig Tatsachen verdreht und propagiert. Wahrscheinlich spielt er darauf an, dass hier jemand genau so was tut.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nein. Auch die Wörterbücher, z.B. Duden, definiert Propaganda als "systematische Verbreitung politischer, weltanschaulicher o. ä. Ideen und Meinungen". Imaginäre Sündenböcke zu bestimmen, oder allgemeine politische Dummheit, würde ich nicht als Propaganda einstufen.

Comment: Wenn Du imaginäre Sündenböcke nicht für Teil von Propagande hälst, würde ich mir nochmal die Vorgeschichte und Geschichte des 2. Weltkriegs anschauen...

Comment: @jarnbjo: Ich verstehe deine Einwände ehrlich gesagt nicht. Das Bestimmen imaginärer Sündenböcke in einem politisch relevanten Thema wie hier geschehen *ist* die Verbreitung einer politischen *und* weltanschaulichen Idee bzw. Meinung. Wir können allenfalls noch diskutieren, ob das Kriterium der *systematischen* Verbreitung erfüllt ist, sprich, ob die Aussage über die Umweltschützer dazu ihre eigene landesweite Werbekampagne bekommen muss, oder ob es genügt, dass die Aussage vom amtierenden Staatschef in ebendieser Funktion veröffentlicht wurde.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Und ich deine Einwände nicht. Weder erkenne ich in dieser einen Aussage eine politische oder weltanschauliche Meinung, höchstens eine irrtümliche rechtliche oder wissenschaftliche Meinung, noch sehe ich ein, dass eine einzelne Aussage systematisch sein kann. Die politische Führung in Brasilien mag man vielleicht im Gesamtbild als orwellhaft betrachten, aber nicht diese eine Aussage.

Answer (score 0):

Richtig, es bezieht sich auf George Orwell und insbesondere auf sein bekanntestes Werk *1984*.

Was genau *orwellhaft* bedeutet, ist jedoch umstritten. Ein längerer Artikel des *The Guardian* schließt mit:

> Many on the right think Orwell speaks for them and they speak for Orwell. Many on the left think the equal and opposite. Plenty in the middle feel the same. Orwell is rightly praised as a prophet, a teller of uncomfortable truths and a writer who has changed the way we see and talk about the world. But most of us read into him what we want to see. He may hold up a mirror to the world - but our own faces tend to get in the way. ([Do you really know what ‘Orwellian’ means?](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2014/nov/11/reading-group-orwellian-1984))

Sprich, was *orwellhaft* konkret bedeutet, hängt sehr stark von der eigenen Weltanschauung ab. Auf jeden Fall geht es im Werk um das Leben in einer absurden, totalitären Gesellschaft, in der die Regierung den Einzelnen massiv durch Propaganda manipuliert.

Zitat:

> Denn wie können wir schon
>   wissen, ob zwei und zwei wirklich vier ist? Oder ob das Gesetz der Schwerkraft stimmt? Oder ob die
>   Vergangenheit unveränderlich ist? Wenn beides, Vergangenheit und Außenwelt, nur in der Vorstellung
>   existieren und man die Vorstellung einfach beherrschen kann – was dann?